# Calculating Vectors

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-science

Good Afternoon,

I'm a a little stumped as to how to implement this formula into Excel, I already have the data and understand what the formula is supposed to do, but I cannot fathom for the life of me how to write the formula

KANDS = {[KSCOEFS]t[KSCOEFS]}(to power-1)[KSCOEFS]t[OBS]

I understand the first part of the rhs of the equation is an array calculation and usues MMULT with a transpose for the second array which makes sense as the array size would be the same and returns a value when used alone, but the next part, the OBS is only one column wide but the same number of rows as the KSCOEFS, that just returns a #VALUE.

But how do I get it to calculate the KANDS section which is one column wide and 8 rows long? this would need to be calculated 31 times

In my mind, the RHS is ={POWER(MMULT(KSCOEFS),TRANSPOSE(KSCOEFS)),-1)}*MMULT(KSCOEFS,TRANSPOSE(OBS)), but this doesn't help answer how I get a solution vector in KANDS.

Link to example sheet - This only needs to work for one wavelength as it should be repeatable all the way along the wavelength as KANDS needs to be solved for each wavelength

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AljqtqHbhTTigcsSgL69h1YkeE9_MA?e=xBGDbJ

Comment: Rather than pictures, paste copiable data. Use a much smaller example for obvious reasons, together with your expected result(s).

Comment: Hello, See edited question with link to excel sheet :)

Comment: Thanks. So do columns O:P contain your manually calculated expected results? If not, can you add some, if not all, of them?

Comment: The columns you mentioned are just a key as to what is in the columns, but for the purpose of working out the equation, they are not important. The result of the equation should be in the EQUATION sheet, column C. Thing is, i can’t figure out how to to have all the cells populated per wavelength. SUMPRODUCT springs to mind, but i don’t think that can be done over multiple cells?

Comment: Ah, I was hoping for one or two manually calculated expected results so that I would at least know whether my attempted formulas are along the right lines.

Comment: That’s just it, i can get a result if I do {POWER(MMULT(KSCOEFS,TRANSPOSE(KSCOEFS)),-1)}, but if I try with the OBS, I just get an error.

Comment: But I still can’t get my head around how to fill the solution vector of KANDS

Comment: @Jos I have some answers, but still not sure if it's right?

I used the following formula in Excel to answer the following matrix formula(I realised that i'd made a foul up, it wasn't POWER, it was MINVERSE I was supposed to use...I'm out of practice with Matrix Multiplications)

Formula = KANDS = {[KSCOEFS]t[KSCOEFS]}-1[KSCOEFS]t[OBS]

Excel Formula = {MINVERSE(MMULT('KSCOEFS 400'!$B$2:$K$35,TRANSPOSE('KSCOEFS 400'!$B$2:$K$35)))*MMULT(TRANSPOSE($B$2:$B$35),'KSCOEFS 400'!$B$2:$K$35)}

This gives an answer for K1 in KANDS of 5.189E13, K2 = -3.78406E13

Comment: But that's my whole point. I too have no idea what the answer *should* be, so I can't even begin to write any formulas. Usually an OP will be able to ascertain - via manual means - their desired result, though will not know how to go about obtaining that result using code/formulas. In your case you don't even know what the result *should* be, ditto for me, so I'm afraid I'm stuck.